# Apache ignoring extension and executing other files through fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I've got a problem with configuring apache to run only files with `.php` extension through FastCGI. 
Sample VirtualHost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.185:80>
    ServerName host1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www/host1.example.com/WWW/

    SuexecUserGroup host1 www

    <Directory "/home/www/host1.example.com/WWW/">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FcgidWrapper /home/www/host1.example.com/fcgi/php5.fcgi
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, that it also runs files like `whats.new.in.php.6.html` (basically every file containing `.php` followed by the dot) as fastcgi instead serving it as static content. I've tried changing **AddHandler** to

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php$
```

With no luck - php files were not interpreted and served as plain text.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this. Instead of `AddHandler` I used `AddType` with handler name:

```
AddType fcgid-script .php
```

And now it works only for `*.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to remove the dollar sign.  The `AddHandler` option takes the extension, not a regular expression or glob.  So the correct line would be in your original

```
# With or without the leading dot, mod_mime doesn't care
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
```

As to why its flagging html files as executable, I have no idea--there could be a flag somewhere setting it, perhaps in a default configuration.  However, as a workaround, you can [REMOVE the handler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#removehandler) for .html files by using the following, so that they will be treated as normal text/html files.

```
RemoveHandler .html
```

Comment: Please read carefully. This is what I have and it is still executing if there is `.php` in the file name followed by the dot. Dollar sign was my first guess but failed so I'm still using the line without dollar.

Comment: I blame the travel time and the tryptophan. :)  Updated my answer to actually answer your question.

Comment: Does not work, besides there is no handler for HTML files. HTML was only example, it applies to all extensions: `test.php.gif`, `test.php.txt` etc. are all treated as fastcgi scripts, so even if removing handler would work, there is no way to define all possible extensions to remove handler.